# Swing - Add button JList

Tags: java, swing, awt

I have to desing a fleetmanagment for my Swing Project i created a add button but i cant figure out have to make a delete button any help? Here's my Code for addbutton.

```
addbutton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
            //make sure you preserve the previously selected list items
            int size = rightlist.getModel().getSize();
            Set objects = new LinkedHashSet();
            for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
                objects.add(rightlist.getModel().getElementAt(i));
            }
            objects.addAll(Arrays.asList(leftlistfreight.getSelectedValues()));

            rightlist.setListData(objects.toArray());
        }
    });
```

EDIT!

ArrayList Code

```
List<FreightBoats> freightBoat = new ArrayList<FreightBoats>();
    freightBoat.add(new FreightBoats("Boat Name : Stefan |","This Boat can Carry Conitainer : ",25000));
    freightBoat.add(new FreightBoats("Boat Name : Sminroff |","This Boat can Carry Conitainer : ",30000));
    freightBoat.add(new FreightBoats("Boat Name : Container 2000 |","This Boat can Carry Conitainer : ",2500));
    freightBoat.add(new FreightBoats("Boat Name : Windows |","This Boat can Carry Conitainer : ",25200));
    freightBoat.add(new FreightBoats("Boat Name : Unhuman |","This Boat can Carry Conitainer : ",200));
    freightBoat.add(new FreightBoats("Boat Name : ElPolako |","This Boat can Carry Conitainer : ",300000));
    freightBoat.add(new FreightBoats("Boat Name : BrainDead |","This Boat can Carry Conitainer : ",10000));
    freightBoat.add(new FreightBoats("Boat Name : WSHR | ","This Boat can Carry Conitainer : ",34005));
    freightBoat.add(new FreightBoats("Boat Name : Grolsch ","This Boat can Carry Conitainer : ",10565
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't play with Arrays or ArrayLists. There is no need to recreate the ListModel by using the setListData() method.

Instead updates should be done directly to the `ListModel`.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Lists](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html). The `ListDemo` example shows you how to both "add" and "remove" items from the ListModel by using the "Hire" and "Fire" buttons.

Comment: I think i need to use ArrayList beacouse i keep my boats names in a array. I put the array code.Check it out and tell me if there is another alternative i can use. Thanks

Comment: @JohnJohnson, `I think i need to use ArrayList beacouse i keep my boats names in a array.` - No you don't. The designe of your application is wrong. If you display data in a JList then the data is stored in a ListModel. There is no need for a separate Array. `if there is another alternative` - The design and usage of Swing components is based on Model-View-Controller design. I already suggested the proper solution and pointed you to a working example. Using a separate Array goes against this design principle. There is no need for the Array. The ListModel has methods to access the data.